# Child object moving too far from parent object

Tags: animation, constraints, parent

im trying to make a robot arm pick something up and put it down somewhere else. to do this, im using the child of constraint so i can animate parenting and unparenting (since you can animate the influence).
When i move the robot arm, the child object moves in the same direction but too far.

Comment: Maybe you have also parented the object, try to unparent, if this doesn't work please share the file on https://blend-exchange.com/